# Ошибка в отправке формы php

Tags: php

Всем привет! При отправки формы, в которой все введено , возвращает ошибку "Введите пароль". В чем проблема? Я уже попробовал ставить @.

```
require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;
if (@isset($data['register'])){
  // Здесь регистрация

  $errors = array();
  if($data['mail'] == '0'){
    $errors[] = 'Введите почту';
  }
  if($data['name'] == ''){
    $errors[] = 'Введите Имя';
  }
  if(trim($data['password']) == ''){
    @$errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
  }
  if(trim($data['repeatPassword']) != $data['password']){
    $errors[] = 'Повторный пароль введен неверно';
  }
  if(R::count('users',"name = ?", array($data['name'])) > 0){
    $errors[] =  "<div>Пользователь с таким именем уже существует</div>";
  }
  if(R::count('users',"mail = ?", array($data['mail'])) > 0){
    $errors[] = "<div>Пользователь с таким email существует</div>";
  }
  if(empty($errors)){
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->mail = $data['mail'];
    $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    R::store($user);
    echo "<div>Вы успешно зарегистрировались!</div>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<div id='errors'>".array_shift($errors)."</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: В форме есть такой атрибут "method" - он у вас указан? Какое у него значение? (вообще неплохо бы показать саму форму. Хотя бы теги FORM и INPUT)

Comment: И на всякий случай (вдруг больше никто вам этого не скажет) - не нужно использовать `@`. Даже не пробуйте

Comment: method = "POST"

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинт на `if(trim($data['password']) == ''){` и посмотрите что в массиве `$data` (если не настроен xdebug, можно вывести значение массива через `var_dump()`)